# In formal writing, should I reply to this email in this case

Tags: tense, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

So, I have received the email, from two employers, with some tasks for me to do for the next week. However, pointing at me on the end of the mail with:

```
@MyName "I'll send you another email next Monday with all the info on what you will do."
```

Should I reply to this email like:

```
- "Okay, talk to you on the Monday next week."

- "Okay, I'm looking forward - to it/to talk to you."
```

or how should I write in some simple formal format, or should I just ignore it and wait for the next email?

Comment: You don't use _talk_ for exchanging emails, not for formal emails at least, I guess. Take a look at these: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151980/what-informal-and-formal-letter-e-mail-closings-are-used-the-most and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332/which-expressions-can-be-used-to-close-an-email

Comment: Also you can omit *the* in "the Monday".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Look forward to **hearing** from you next week
>   Look forward to your **follow up** email next week

would be a standard ways of emailing back your anticipation of their email

You would usually use **talk** if you were actually going to have a conversation with them via a conference call or webcast